# Espresso tests failing due to repainting the screen by Android Camera Intent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

I am having an activity which has camera, and having a mask over the camera which is done by `onDraw()` method, I was writing test cases for the navigation drawer which is above the camera screen, but getting error as

> Perhaps the main thread has not gone idle within a reasonable amount of time? There could be an animation or something constantly repainting the screen. Or the activity is doing network calls on creation? See the threaddump logs. For your reference the last time the event queue was idle before your activity launch request was 1472804618974 and now the last time the queue went idle was: 1472804618974. If these numbers are the same your activity might be hogging the event queue

I have already turned off the animation as already mentioned over
https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/index.html

Don't know what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

> I have already turned off the animation as already mentioned over
>   https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/index.html

This problem occurs not because of turned of animations, but because of `Espresso` framework character: `Espresso` depends on your actual application context.

> Espresso for Android is perfect and fast test automation framework,
>   but it has one important limitation - you are allowed to operate only
>   inside your app under test context.
>
> That means that it is not possible to automate tests for such app
>   features like:
>
> - application push notifications
> - contact synchronization
> - navigating from another app to your app under test,
>
> since you have to deal with other apps from the mobile device -
>   Notification Bar, Contacts or People app, etc.
>
> From: http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html

It means that `Espresso` tests are based on UI thread and waiting when the main thread is idle().

> Perhaps the main thread has not gone idle within a reasonable amount of time? There could be an animation or something constantly repainting the screen. Or the activity is doing network calls on creation? See the threaddump logs. For your reference the last time the event queue was idle before your activity launch request was 1472804618974 and now the last time the queue went idle was: 1472804618974. If these numbers are the same your activity might be hogging the event queue.

This means that your main thread is actually  busy and Espresso can't perform any new actions, it's waiting for free idling resources to run.

To solve this problem you have these options:

- write your own custom `Espresso IdlingResource` to say Espresso when he can perform action, in other words: `IdlingResource` tells Espresso when the main thread is idle and ready to take a new actions.
- exclude `appcompat` and `support-v4` from `espresso` libs : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/issues/56
- I suppose that you're running `Camera` using an Android `Intent`, so it isn't included in your actual app context, it's not displayed on your apps activity/fragment. If it is true, try to use [`UiAutomator`](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/uiautomator/index.html) along with [`Espresso`](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/index.html) framework. Read: http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html
- instead of `Espresso` try to use `Robotium`, `Appium` or another instrumentation framework without this limitation.

Already, I'm using along `Espresso`, `Robotium` and `UiAutomator`, so don't be afraid to work with mix of them.

Hope it help

Answer (score 1):

So i was able to solve my issue.
The problem was occurring due to continuous calling method `invalidate()` from `onDraw()`.
Instead i replaced it with `postInvalidateDelayed()`, and for certain conditions(like animations) only used `invalidate()`. 
It helped! :)
Avoid continuous repainting screen.